# Getting blank page when running RSpec tests for get 'new'

Tags: rspec, capybara

I am getting an empty page as response when running the following RSpec test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe FriendshipsController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  render_views

  before(:each) do
    @user = User.create!(:email => "max@mustermann.com", :password => "mustermann", :password_confirmation => "mustermann")
    @friend = User.create!(:email => "john@doe.com", :password => "password", :password_confirmation => "password")    
    sign_in @user
  end  

  describe "GET 'new'" do

    it "should be successful" do
      get 'new', :user_id => @user.id
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should show all registered users on Friendslend, except the logged in user" do
      get 'new', :user_id => @user.id

      page.should have_select("Add new friend")
      page.should have_content("div.users")
      page.should have_selector("div.users li", :count => 1)
    end

    it "should not contain the logged in user" do
      get 'new', :user_id => @user.id
      response.should_not have_content(@user.email)
    end
  end
end
```

I only get a blank page when running the RSpec test. 
With blank page I mean there is no other HTML content other than the DOCTYPE declaration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

Interestingly, RSpec tests for post 'create' work fine. Any hints?

I am using Rails 3.2 with spec-rails, cucumber and capybara (instead of webrat).

Comment: I'm curious, did you ever found a solution to this problem?

Comment: also curious about a solution to this..

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a solution yet...

Comment: Is there anything meaningful that shows up in the test log when you run these tests? What is your controller doing?

Comment: Did you try to put `get 'new'..` in the `before` block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing types of tests. Capybara, which provides the `page` object is used in request specs by calling `visit path`.

In order to fix your problem, you need to be looking at the `response` object instead of the `page` object.

If you want to test content with capybara, the way that you would build that test would look something like this:

```
visit new_user_session_path
fill_in "Email", :with => @user.email
fill_in "Password", :with => @user.password
click_button "Sign in"
visit new_friendships_path(:user_id => @user.id)
page.should have_content("Add new friend")
```

That code should be placed in a request spec instead of a controller spec, by convention.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to solve this by adding the following in my spec_helper.rb file:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.render_views
end
```

Optionally you can call `render_views` in each controller spec individually.

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/features/controller_specs/render_views.feature

Comment: Thank you sir, after hours searching the web, you helped me